# Validate Radio Button Groups

Tags: vb.net, validation

How can I validate at least one of the radio buttons in a groupbox is checked?  I am validating all the text controls are properly populated like this;

```
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            If ctrl.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter information in " & ctrl.Name, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
```

Is there a similar method for radio buttons as I can't seem to find a logical way to complete this.

Comment: When you layout the form, you can (should) set one as the default, the user cant uncheck any and you wont have to perform any check at all.  Otherwise the checkboxes will be found in the GroupBox.Controls not Me.Controls

Comment: Yes, of course! I'm over thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
Dim uncheckedRadios = From radio In Me.groupbox1.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)()
                      Where Not radio.Checked
                      Select radio.Name
Dim anyUnchecked As Boolean = uncheckedRadios.Any()

If anyUnchecked Then
    Dim uncheckedNames = String.Join(",", uncheckedRadios)
    MessageBox.Show("Please check all radio-buttons, these are not checked: " & uncheckedNames, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return
End If
```